# Login page & registration page and other application pages in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am confused over a situation. I am not sure which approach to take.

I am developing an SPA using angularJs.

I have login page, registration page and other application pages.

The layouts of login page, registration page and application pages are different from each other. Which means, different css classes.

Now my question is, Shall I create 3 different Layouts along with 3 different app.js files or I should stick to one and manage somehow?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/multiple-named-views

Answer (score 1):

You would create 3 different HTML templates for each of your views which you can keep as three separate HTML files so you might have a folder named templates which has the files

login.html

register.html

about.html

Your application would then swap in each of the views depending on the route being requested.

You do not need a separate .js file for each view.

See the below fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/yaprak/789Ks/1/

Rather than use raw html as the template in the above example, you can provide a link to a file e.g.

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state("login", {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: "Ctrl1"
      }).state("about", {
        url: "/about",
        templateUrl: "templates/about.html",
        controller: "Ctrl2"
    });
```

Comment: Do i need to have ng-view in login.html and register.html?

Comment: No! Think of  <div ng-view></div> as a placeholder for your views. Basically, it's where your view will be displayed when requested by the router.

Comment: This didn't work. The login.html tried to open inside index.html layout.

Comment: Yes that's how Angular works. You have the index.html, inside which you have your <div ng-view></div> . This is where your views are displayed, so yes your views are displayed within the index.html. It's a single page application, so your views are displayed within a single page which is your index.html page.